# Swift Toolbar button triggers a exec_bad_instruction only on one scene

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode, storyboard

I'm changing my app to start to use toolbar buttons for the main pages instead of a menu. All of the menu links work and the toolbar buttons work on every page except one. When I click on the button the app freezes, and Xcode brings me to this line: 
'weak var itemDetailPage = segue.destination as? ItemDetailViewController' with this error: 
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
All the variables are nil.

Any help would be monumental!

Here is the code for the view controller it is specifically happening on:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Alamofire


@objc protocol FavRefreshLikeCountsDelegate: class {
    func updateLikeCounts(_ likeCount: Int)
}

@objc protocol FavRefreshReviewCountsDelegate: class {
    func updateReviewCounts(_ reviewCount: Int)
}

class FavouriteItemsViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    var populationItems = false
    var selectedSubCategoryId:Int = 0
    var selectedCityId:Int = 1
    var selectedCityLat: String!
    var selectedCityLng: String!
    var items = [ItemModel]()
    var currentPage = 0
    var loginUserId:Int = 0
    weak var selectedCell : AnnotatedPhotoCell!

    @IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    var defaultValue: CGPoint!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        if self.revealViewController() != nil {
            menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
            menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

        }

        collectionView!.register(AnnotatedPhotoCell.classForCoder(), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "AnnotatedPhotoCell")

        if let layout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? PinterestLayout {
            layout.delegate = self
        }
        loadLoginUserId()
        loadFavouriteItems()

        defaultValue = collectionView?.frame.origin
        animateCollectionView()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        updateNavigationStuff()
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
    }


    override func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        loadFavouriteItems()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {


        weak var itemCell = sender as? AnnotatedPhotoCell
        weak var itemDetailPage = segue.destination as? ItemDetailViewController
        itemDetailPage!.selectedItemId = Int((itemCell!.item?.itemId)!)!
        itemDetailPage!.selectedShopId = Int((itemCell!.item?.itemShopId)!)!
        itemDetailPage!.favRefreshLikeCountsDelegate = self
        itemDetailPage!.favRefreshReviewCountsDelegate = self
        selectedCell = itemCell
        updateBackButton()

    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        var cell : AnnotatedPhotoCell

        cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AnnotatedPhotoCell", for: indexPath) as! AnnotatedPhotoCell
        cell.item = items[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).item]

        let imageURL = configs.imageUrl + items[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).item].itemImage

        cell.imageView?.loadImage(urlString: imageURL) {  (status, url, image, msg) in
            if(status == STATUS.success) {
                print(url + " is loaded successfully.")
                self.items[indexPath.item].itemImageBlob = image
            }else {
                print("Error in loading image" + msg)
            }
        }

        cell.imageView.alpha = 0
        cell.captionLabel.alpha = 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
            cell.imageView.alpha = 1.0
            cell.captionLabel.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: nil)

        return cell

    }


    func updateBackButton() {
        let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
        backItem.title = ""
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
    }

    func updateNavigationStuff() {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = language.favouritePageTitle
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: customFont.boldFontName, size: CGFloat(customFont.boldFontSize))!,  NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:UIColor.white]
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = Common.instance.colorWithHexString(configs.barColorCode)
    }

    func loadLoginUserId() {
        let plistPath = Common.instance.getLoginUserInfoPlist()

        let myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: plistPath)
        if let dict = myDict {
            loginUserId           = Int(dict.object(forKey: "_login_user_id") as! String)!

            print("Login User Id : " + String(loginUserId))
        } else {
            print("WARNING: Couldn't create dictionary from LoginUserInfo.plist! Default values will be used!")
        }
    }

    func loadFavouriteItems() {
        if self.currentPage == 0 {
            _ = EZLoadingActivity.show("Loading...", disableUI: true)
        }
        Alamofire.request(APIRouters.GetFavouriteItems( loginUserId, configs.pageSize, self.currentPage)).responseCollection {
            (response: DataResponse<[Item]>) in

            if self.currentPage == 0 {
                _ = EZLoadingActivity.hide()
            }

            if response.result.isSuccess {
                if let items: [Item] = response.result.value {
                    if(items.count > 0) {
                        for item in items {
                            let oneItem = ItemModel(item: item)
                            self.items.append(oneItem)
                            self.currentPage+=1

                        }
                    }
                }

                self.collectionView!.reloadData()

            } else {
                print(response)
            }
        }

    }

    func animateCollectionView() {

        moveOffScreen()

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0,
                       usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9,
                       initialSpringVelocity: 0.9, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
                        self.collectionView?.frame.origin = self.defaultValue
        }, completion: nil)
    }

    fileprivate func moveOffScreen() {
        collectionView?.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: (collectionView?.frame.origin.x)!,
                                               y: (collectionView?.frame.origin.y)! + UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
    }

}


extension FavouriteItemsViewController : PinterestLayoutDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView:UICollectionView, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath indexPath:IndexPath , withWidth width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

        let item = items[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).item]

        let boundingRect =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))

        let size = CGSize(width: item.itemImageWidth, height: item.itemImageHeight)
        var rect : CGRect
        if item.itemImageBlob != nil {
            rect  = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: item.itemImageBlob!.size, insideRect: boundingRect)
        }else{
            rect  = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: size, insideRect: boundingRect)

        }

        return rect.size.height
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, heightForAnnotationAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath, withWidth width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let annotationPadding = CGFloat(4)
        let annotationHeaderHeight = CGFloat(17)
        let height = annotationPadding + annotationHeaderHeight + annotationPadding + 30
        return height
    }
}

extension FavouriteItemsViewController : FavRefreshLikeCountsDelegate, FavRefreshReviewCountsDelegate {
    func updateLikeCounts(_ likeCount: Int) {
        if selectedCell != nil {
            selectedCell.lblLikeCount.text = "\(likeCount)"
        }
    }

    func updateReviewCounts(_ reviewCount: Int) {
        if selectedCell != nil {
            selectedCell.lblReviewCount.text = "\(reviewCount)"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try be checking your ItemDetailViewController.
for example:

```
if segue.identifier == "ItemDetailVC" {
    weak var itemCell = sender as? AnnotatedPhotoCell
    weak var itemDetailPage = segue.destination as? ItemDetailViewController
    ...
}
```

Comment: I believe that is the problem. My tool bar has nothing to do with items, but every time I click a lick it registers it as an item. I have a menu button as well that it doesn't register as an item.